# Number of ways to paint a grid, such that each 2 x 2 grid inside it contains each color only once

Tags: discrete-mathematics

1) Is my answer correct to finding the number of possible ways to paint a 2008 x 2008 grid with 4 colors, such that each 2 x 2 grid inside it contains each color only once?

My answer : Select the top left corner and we have 4 choices, then we have 3 choices for its right place. And then that row will have to be the repeating pattern of those 2 numbers. The next row's first two columns have 2 choices and the rest should be repetitive, and then for each row we have 2 choices for selecting the first two numbers and then it will be repetitive, and we can do the exact thing but with repeating patterns in each column instead of each row, so :
$$2\cdot( 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2^{2007} )$$
And since we have counted some answers twice (the ones that are repetitive both in rows and in columns), we should subtract those :
$$2\cdot( 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2^{2007}) - 4! $$

2) If my answer isn't correct please explain my mistake to me, and if it is, then what happens to the 4! if the number of columns and/or rows are odd? Would it be harder to calculate the number of answers that has been calculated twice? How would it be calculated?

3) Can the repeating pattern be proven to be needed in each and every answer? (Is there any answer without pattern in rows or columns?)

Comment: The claim that the top row must repeat two colors is false.  The array
$$\begin {array} {c c c c} 1&2&3&4\\3&4&1&2\\1&2&3&4\\3&4&1&2 \end {array}$$
can be continued in the obvious way to any desired size

Comment: In the paragraph which I wrote my answer, at the end I mentioned that we can do the repeating pattern for columns too. This one has the repeating pattern in the columns

Comment: You should not bury the statement that the repetition can occur in either direction. 
 You should make also clear what you are claiming and what you are not.  The first paragraph claims that one direction must repeat, but 3 asks whether that is true.

Comment: In 1, I asked if my answer is correct, because I'm not sure myself of this answer. I assumed the repeating pattern in either rows or columns or both must be true, because when I wrote unrepeating patterns, I reached a dead-end. But reaching a dead-end a couple of times doesn't mean we will reach dead-end "every" time, and such a general statement needs a proof. That's the reason I asked 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that some three consecutive squares in some row have three different colours. That uniquely determines the three squares above and below, and thus the entire three columns, with each column alternating between two colours. The remaining columns must then also alternatingly alternate between these two pairs of colours.

Thus, if the rows don’t alternatingly alternate between two pairs of colours, the columns must, and vice versa, so you’re right to think that at least one of the two must alternate thus.

You don’t need a separate correction for odd numbers of rows or columns. Say there are $m$ rows and $n$ columns. For alternating columns, there are $\binom42=6$ ways to assign pairs of colours to the columns and $n$ independent binary choices for the alternations in the columns, and thus $6\cdot2^n$ choices overall; likewise $6\cdot2^m$ choices if the rows alternate; and $4!$ if both alternate, for a total of

$$
6\cdot\left(2^m+2^n-4\right)\;,
$$

as you correctly found.